# How do I extract the domain from a URL in Perl?

Tags: perl, url

How do I extract the domain out of an URL? Is there a Perl module? I could not find any.

Comment: How about [URI](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI) maybe?

Comment: URI is good. I tend to use Mojo::URL because I'm using other parts of Mojolicious. Either is fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [URI](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI) module.

```perl
my $host = URI->new($url)->host
```

If the URL could be a relative URL,

```perl
my $host = URI->new_abs($url, $base_url)->host
```

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to parse url into it's components.

Following method utilizes `split` function.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my $url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64671082/plugin-perl-how-do-i-extract-the-domain-out-of-an-url';
my($proto,$host,@path) = split '[:/]+', $url;
my $url_parts;

$url_parts->@{qw/proto host path/} = ($proto, $host, \@path);

say Dumper($url_parts);
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = {
          'path' => [
                      'questions',
                      '64671082',
                      'plugin-perl-how-do-i-extract-the-domain-out-of-an-url'
                    ],
          'proto' => 'https',
          'host' => 'stackoverflow.com'
        };
```

Comment: There are various ways that this won't work since the part after the :// is sometime not a host or has additional data.